# Using %s in substring

Tags: python

```
inputData = raw_input('time:')    
find_elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), '%s')]"% inputData)))
```

I do not know exactly why my code isn't working. I'm trying to pass my rawinput. If I get rid of %s and just put a string. It works. By not working I mean, the script is suppose to stop scrolling until certain time I do in raw_input but it doesn't but if I just pass in my string without %s it stops and works just as I wish to.

Comment: It sounds like you have one string that works (the one you hard-coded) and one that doesn't (the one you've made with `%s`). Print them out and spot the difference.

Comment: what means `isn't working` - do you get error message or what ?

Comment: @furas In this case it needs to stop scrolling but continues to scroll. but if I get rid of %s it stops at the desired amount I want.

Comment: As @smarx said - compare both strings

Comment: Yes. I compared the both string by doing this string  = "//*[contains(text(), '%s')]" % inputDate
print string
//*[contains(text(), '8 mins')]
Just how I wanted it to. but when I use that in my actual function it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use tuple for string formatting:

```
"%s" % (inputData)
```

**UPDATE**
This fixed the problem, but I do not know why? I am not sure why this worked and fixed the problem. As suggested in comments, `(inputData)` is not even a tuple. And string formatting does not need the second argument to be tuple. The second argument can be a string.

Comment: I have no explanation for why this would fix something... `(inputData)` is *not* a tuple. `(inputData,)` would be. Regardless, you can certainly just use a string in this sort of construction `"%s" % "hello world"` works just fine.